# Close Hamburger Menu When mobile menu Link is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

when I click the menu item the page loads but the menu stays open.

this is the Mobile Menu it JSX:

```
const MobileMenu = () =>  {


  const navigation = [
    { link: '/applications', text: 'Applications' },
    { link: '/multi-media', text: 'Media' },
    { link: '/websites', text: 'Websites' },
    { link: '/mobile-apps', text: 'Mobile' },
    { link: '/support', text: 'Support' },
    { link: '/contact', text: 'Contact' },
    { link: '/', text: 'Login' },
  ];

  return (
      <NavMenuContainer>
        <NavList>
        <div className="flex pb-4 lg:px-6 lg:hidden">
        <Searchbar id="mobile-search" />
      </div>
          {navigation.map(nav => (
            <NavLink key={nav.text}>
              <Link href={nav.link}><a>
                {nav.text}
              </a></Link>
            </NavLink>
          ))}
        </NavList>
        </NavMenuContainer>
  );
};




export default MobileMenu
```

this is NAV the MobileMenu menu is in(JSX:

```
export default function HamburgerMenu(props) {

  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);


  //change
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    let dd = document.body;
    dd.classList.toggle("navbar-mobile");
    setOpen(!isOpen);

  };



  return (
    <Theburger>
      <HamburgerMenuContainer>
        <MenuToggle toggle={toggleMenu} isOpen={isOpen} />
        <MenuContainer
          initial={false}
          animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
          variants={menuVariants}
          transition={menuTransition}
        >
          <ContentContainer>
            <MobileMenu isOpen={isOpen} />
         </ContentContainer>
        </MenuContainer>
      </HamburgerMenuContainer>
    </Theburger>
  );
}
```

this is the website main menu it TSX:

```
const Navbar: FC<NavbarProps> = ({ links }) => (
  <NavbarRoot>
    <Container>
      <div className={s.nav}>
        <div className="flex items-center">
        <Link href="/"><a>
          <div className="logo">
              <Image width={106} height={27} src="/logo.svg" alt="brand" />
            </div>
            </a></Link>
           <nav className={s.navMenu}>
     
              {[...links3 ].map((page) => (
                <span key={page.url}>
                  <Link href={page.url!}>
                    <a className={s.link}>
                      {page.name}
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </span>
              ))}
       
       
            {links?.map((l) => (
              <Link href={l.href} key={l.href}>
                <a className={s.link}>{l.label}</a>
              </Link>
            ))}
         </nav>
        </div>
   
        <div className="flex items-center justify-end flex-1 space-x-8 mr-5">
          <UserNav />
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-end flex-2">
          <Nav />
       </div>

    
      </div>
 
    </Container>
  </NavbarRoot>
)

export default Navbar
```

Its a nextjs app Im using a Layout component in _app.tsx not sure if that matters but it really shouldn't, I Missed tsx with jsx and according to the docs at NextJS and javascript in general mixing them shouldn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to give the state as a prop to your toggle menu function.
Thus isOpen is always false and the state gets changed always to true.

Change your toggleMenu() to toggleMenu(isOpen) and it's fine.

```
export default function HamburgerMenu(props) {

  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);


  //change
  const toggleMenu = (myState) => {
    let dd = document.body;
    dd.classList.toggle("navbar-mobile");
    setOpen(!isOpen);

  };



  return (
    <Theburger>
      <HamburgerMenuContainer>
        <MenuToggle toggle={()=>toggleMenu(isOpen)} isOpen={isOpen} />
        <MenuContainer
          initial={false}
          animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
          variants={menuVariants}
          transition={menuTransition}
        >
          <ContentContainer>
            <MobileMenu isOpen={isOpen} />
         </ContentContainer>
        </MenuContainer>
      </HamburgerMenuContainer>
    </Theburger>
  );
}
```

The reason you're running into the menu being always visible, is because when react compiles the function, the initial value is used whether it was changed or not. Resulting in the following function to always console log "initial" even when the state has changed.

```
function A() {
    const [textState, setTextState] = useState('initial');
    const printState = () => {
        console.log(textState);
        setTextState('changed');
}
    return <button onClick={()=>printState()}>Print me</button>
}
```

this behaves different in the following two scenarios where either the state is from the parent or the props are given to the function.

Parent Props

```
function B({textState, setTextState}) {
    const printState = () => {
        console.log(textState);
        setTextState('changed');
}
    return <button onClick={()=>printState()}>Print me</button>
}
```

In function B the printState function is given as a prop and the function is rerendered when the props change, causing also the printState function to be compiled again with the new props causing to console log changed instead of initial.

The other option is handling the state in the component itself and giving the state as a prop to our function.

```
function C() {
    const [textState, setTextState] = useState('initial');
    const printState = (prop) => {
        console.log(prop);
        setTextState('changed');
}
    return <button onClick={()=>printState(textState)}>Print me</button>
}
```

Here the prop is given directly to the printState function, while the printState function is not being recompiled the updated state is given as a prop and handled accordingly

Comment: Tried this already. It disable the close menu and doesn't affect the modileMenu links, Are you aware the mobileMenu is a different component?

Comment: It's not about mobileMenu, but about toggleMenu. I've extended my answer with examples to clarify why and how functions are compiled with states in react

Comment: Your answer makes sense and the logic is good but the problem persists. This could be beyond the scope of my question, thanks for trying. I'll keep you posted as to how I solve it.